# How to connect tata photon in X window manager in ubuntu 14.04 using command line

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, internet

Due to some reason I had to shift from Gnome to X(basic X). So here on the desktop nothing appears (no launcher, no menu bar, nothing) but we can open command line in it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. (I have started X window manager using `startx` from the `tty1`).

Applications can be opened using terminal (for example the command Firefox opens the Firefox browser). Now I need to connect to the internet. I have tata photon and I don't know how to connect to the internet using it.

1. If I may know how to open the network manager using command line, I will connect tata photon with it but can it really connect to internet in X.
2. Or else can we connect to internet using command line. If yes then please tell me in detail since I have just shifted to Ubuntu from Windows.

Comment: Which X window manager? That's a category of programs, not the name of a specific program.

Comment: The problem started when i used the boot-repair application simply and closed it before its completion. The next time i rebooted my PC it was in an infinite login screen and i did some things from one of the answers from ask ubuntu to resolve the infinite loop problem but nothing helped. So i removed lightdm and i thought to reinstall it again but after uninstalling it i was not able to reinstall it since i was not able to connect to the internet and i had to login to connect to the internet which could not happen. Now even the login screen is not appearing.

Comment: So i thouht of using the X window manager and thereby connect to the internet and again install lightdm and resolve the login infinte loop problem.